# Restoring a TDE Encrypted Database Backup to a Different Server - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, tde

Two years ago, I used the below code to encrypt (TDE) the database in SQL Server 2008

```
USE MASTER; 
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Strong Password'
GO

USE MASTER; 
CREATE CERTIFICATE DB_CER WITH SUBJECT = 'DB Certificate'
GO

USE DB

GO 
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH 
ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY 
SERVER CERTIFICATE DB_CER ; 
GO

USE  DB
ALTER DATABASE  DB
SET ENCRYPTION ON ; 
GO

USE master; 
GO 
BACKUP CERTIFICATE DB_CER 
TO FILE = 'c:\Backup\certificate_DB_Certificate.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY
(FILE = 'c:\Backup\certificate_DB_Key.pvk',
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Strong Password')
```

I took full backup for DB Database and the certificate_DB_Certificate.cer & certificate_DB_Key.pvk and save it to my hard drive.
After two years I used different PC to restore the MASTER KEY & the CERTIFICATE, so I can to restore the Backup file

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE DB_CER
FROM FILE = 'D:\Backup\certificate_DB_Certificate.cer'     
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'D:\Backup\certificate_OCV_DB_Key.pvk', 
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Strong Password')
```

After I run the code I got this message

> Warning: The certificate you created is expired.

So I delete the CERTIFICATE and I change the Pc date to 2015/Jun (the date when The CERTIFICATE was created) then I re-create the certificate again with successfully completed command, but when I restore the backup file I got this message

> Restore of database 'DB' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot find server certificate with thumbprint '0xFC01AD2683E08A4C8CD6A0F037DC66A945FBA44D'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the source server, is there a certificate with that thumbprint in master? How about on the target server?

Answer (score 0):

The "expired certificate" message was a warning, not an error. You can still use an expired certificate.

Delete the certificate you created with the changed date, then restore the certificate again with the correct date.

Comment: I REALLY would like to know if this worked to OP. because now I'm scared as hell.